# How to get complete order array in observer with event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Tags: magento2, event-observer, onepage-checkout, sales-order

i need a complete order array with all items in observer.

here is event : etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="webhive_sps_controller_success_action" instance="WebHive\SPS\Observer\MyObserver"  />
</event>
```

Observer file: Observer/Myobserver.php

```
<?php

namespace WebHive\SPS\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject as Object;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface {

/*protected $_objectManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
    $this->_objectManager= $objectManager;
}*/


/**
 * @override
 * @see ObserverInterface::execute()
 * @used-by \Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault::_callObserverMethod()
 * @see \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::dispatch()
 * https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/dd47569249206b217e0a9f9a9371e73fd7622724/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php#L91-L92
    $eventParameters = ['controller_action' => $this, 'request' => $request];
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('controller_action_predispatch', $eventParameters)
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

     $event = $observer->getEvent();
     $orderIds = $event->getOrderIds();

    $order_id = $orderIds[0];   
    echo $order_id;                  // prints current order id (e.g : 7)
    // Here i need some function like getOrderDetails that prints order array
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
namespace EwWebHive\SPS\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{ 

    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(  
    OrderRepositoryInterface $OrderRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $OrderRepositoryInterface;

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
           //Custom log:
           $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/stackexchange.log');
           $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
           $logger->addWriter($writer);

           $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
           $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order_ids);           
           $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();   
           $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();

          $logger->info("latest order Id ===>".$order_id.'customer Email ==>'.$customer_email);

          foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
          {
                $logger->info("Item Name ===>".$item->getName());
                $logger->info("Item Sku  ===>".$item->getSku());

          } 

    }


}
```

Comment: I am getting Area code is not set error